# PIG (v0.10.0) excepttion during FILTER operation: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String

Tags: exception, hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig

Here is my (seemingly trivial) PIG script, followed by the exception that it generates:

```
raw_logs = LOAD './Apache-WebLog-Samples.d/access_log.txt' USING TextLoader() AS (line:chararray);

logs = FOREACH raw_logs GENERATE FLATTEN (
    REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL(line, '^(\\S+)\\s+(\\S+)\\s+(\\S+)\\s+\\[([\\w:/]+\\s[+\\-]\\d{4})\\]\\s+"(..*)"\\s+(\\S+)\\s+(\\S+)'))
       AS (remoteAddr:    chararray,
           remoteLogname: chararray,
           user:          chararray,
           date_time:     chararray, 
           request:       chararray,
           httpStatus:          int, <- Here's the problem. But goes away when I set to chararray.
           numBytes:            int);

httpGET200 = FILTER logs BY (request MATCHES '^GET\\s.*') AND (httpStatus == 200);

mylimit = LIMIT httpGET200 40;

DUMP mylimit;
```

PIG SCRIPT

```
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:404)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String

[ ... non meaningful error output removed ... ]

2013-03-13 14:04:10,882 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.SimplePigStats - Script Statistics: 

HadoopVersion   PigVersion  UserId  StartedAt   FinishedAt  Features
2.0.0-cdh4.2.0  0.10.0-cdh4.2.0 nmvega  2013-03-13 14:04:05 2013-03-13 14:04:10 FILTER,LIMIT

Failed!    
Failed Jobs:
JobId   Alias   Feature Message Outputs
job_local1982169921_0001    httpGET200,logs,mylimit,raw_logs        Message: Job failed!    

Input(s):
Failed to read data from "file:///home/user/Dropbox/CodeDEV.d/BIG-DATA-SNIPPETS.d/PIG.d/Apache-WebLog-Samples.d/access_log.txt"

Output(s):
```

EXCEPTION MESSAGES

Everything works except for the 'httpGET200' relation. For reasons not obvious to me, the clause, "httpStatus == 200", causes the exception above. When I remove that clause the problem goes away. Or, alternatively, when I alter the schema and declare 'httpStatus' to be of type "chararray" instead of "int" (as is done above and which is appropriate for HTTP status codes), the problem also goes away... (of course when I do this I have to edit the relation to insert quotes like so: httpStatus == '200').

I checked the input data file and verified that, for every line, the field corresponding to 'httpStatus' is indeed always an integer (... well, a substring representing an integer).

Here, by the way, is the schema as grunt reports it to be (i.e. what is expected):

```
grunt> describe httpGET200;
httpGET200: {remoteAddr: chararray,remoteLogname: chararray,user: chararray,date_time: chararray,request: chararray,httpStatus: int,numBytes: int}
```

I'd like to understand what is happening here (either my misunderstanding or PIG limitation). Can anyone shed light?

Thank you!

Comment: I'd recommend dumping your logs relation to ensure your regex is extracting the http status as you expect.

I'd suspect it's not matching the response code as you expect.

Comment: Thanks seedhead. Actually that's the first thing I did (i.e. dump the logs). The Regex extracted everything exactly as it was designed (i.e. worked as expected for every line of input).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems to me that in case of [REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.0/func.html#regex-extract-all) setting a field in the output schema to int will cause later a `ClassCastException` when an arithmetic operation is performed on that field. Probably because all fields remain and are treated as chararray inside the returned tuple despite the given schema.

As a workaround you may set **all fields** to *chararray* and then perform an explicit cast (conv):

```
logs = FOREACH raw_logs ....
conv = FOREACH logs generate remoteAddr, remoteLogname, user, date_time, 
         request, (int)httpStatus, (int)numBytes;
```

Then you can apply the filter you initially used:

```
httpGET200 = FILTER conv BY (request MATCHES '^GET\\s.*') AND (httpStatus == 200);
```

You can find some more information about a similar issue in [this](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PIG-1965) ticket:

Comment: Lorand thank you. The issue of that ticket is indeed my issue. To paraphrase from it: In PIG, simply declaring that a STRING is an INT, is not sufficient to turn it into an INT. Just to re-emphasize the solution: When using "REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL" just set all fields to "chararray", then perform the extra step of casting, as illustrated above.

Comment: Yes, this is what I suggested. Do you need any more help with this question?

Comment: I just ran into this problem, and I just wanted to say thanks. This is the most ridiculous problem for pig to have.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem trying to compare two integers in FILTER statement in Pig script.
The most elegant solution that I found was using [GenericInvoker](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.0/api/org/apache/pig/builtin/GenericInvoker.html).
So for your problem I would use:

```
--StringToInt would be func that will invoke valueOf method of Integer class for String arg.
DEFINE StringToInt InvokeForInt('java.lang.Integer.valueOf', 'String');


--Now we can use it in our FILTER statement (without need to make projections in order to get right types schema for your tuples)
httpGET200=FILTER logs BY (request MATCHES '^GET\\s.*') AND StringToInt(httpStatus)== 200;
```

Voila!